# Extreme differences in performance for google cloud functions by region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed the [google hello-world function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console) to two different regions:

```
2018-08-13 21:05:14.179 MESZ Cloud Functions UpdateFunction us-central1:helloGET
```

the functions takes by average > 1000ms to run:

```
2018-08-13 21:06:07.735 MESZ helloGET Function execution took 1268 ms, finished with status code: 304
```

deploying to

```
2018-08-13 20:59:49.021 MESZ Cloud Functions CreateFunction europe-west1:helloGET
```

the function runs in an (expected) ms range:

```
2018-08-13 21:05:57.636 MESZ helloGET Function execution took 6 ms, finished with status code: 304
```

The data shown here are from the Stack Driver Logs, so latency is not an issue. The application are exact the same (helloWorld). These results are reproducible. What is going on here? Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's but a fluctuation. Try calcularing the mean and standard deviation for several tries. Also see if it differs between deployments.

Comment: You may have faced an [cold start](https://medium.com/@duhroach/improving-cloud-function-cold-start-time-2eb6f5700f6) in the first execution in `us-central1` execution. Are you sure you didn't execute the `europe-west1` function before? 

I would suggest running several attempts and calculate the mean as @ivan_pozdeev mentioned.

Comment: the execution time values are average values

Comment: Looks strange. What did you deploy? A Python function? I'm aware that they were released very recently, so there may be an issue in there? Other than that, from which region are you calling the functions? This also affects the latency. And what tests are you running? Just out of curiosity. You could edit your post to include this bit.

Comment: Without steps to reproduce the issue provided, we can only make guesses. You should probably ask Google support -- they are in a better position to answer this since they have server logs and stuff.

Comment: You can also run your code under [`profile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html?highlight=profile#module-profile) to localize the problem.